# How to access 'this' within required module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I'm trying to make a module that serves as an API wrapper for a certain site. For organizational purposes, there's a central file with the API class that runs some logic in the constructor and requires the files housing the functions for interacting with the API, separated in different files based on category in the `lib` directory.

```
[API.js]

const Search = require('./lib/search'),
    Character = require('./lib/character')
    ...

class API {
    constructor(apikey, options = {}) {
        /* some logic... */

        this.endpoint = 'https://some.site/'
        this.globalQueries = {
            key: apikey,
            language: options.lang || 'en',
            ...
        }

        this.search = new Search()
        this.character = new Character()
        ...
    }
}

module.exports = API
```

What I want to do is have access to the `this` from this scope in all the required files (probably not the proper wording) so that if, for example, the contents of `./lib/character` are

```
[lib/character.js]

const request = require('request-promise-native')

class Character {
    constructor() {}

    look(name, params = {}) {
        request({
            uri: this.endpoint + 'character/look',
            qs: Object.assign(this.globalQueries, params),
            json: true
        }).then((res) => {
            ...
    }
}

module.exports = Character
```

then not only will all references to `this.endpoint` and `this.globalQueries` work properly, but any other elements in the API.js `this` will too, as well as being sure that the values are retrieved at call time for each of the functions, so that it's up-to-date with any changes.

I'm at a loss for how to make this work, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the class `API` `this` points to the `API` instance. But nowhere has an instance been created yet, so it's hard to know what you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the parent instance to each of the constructors as an argument, like so:

```
class Character {
  constructor (parent) {
    this.parent = parent
  }

  look (name, params = {}) {
    request({
      uri: this.parent.endpoint,
      qs: Object.assign(this.parent.globalQueries, params),
      json: true
    })
  }
}
```

Then, in the API class definition:

```
class API {
  constructor(apikey, options = {}) {
    /* some logic... */

    this.endpoint = 'https://some.site/'
    this.globalQueries = {
      key: apikey,
      language: options.lang || 'en',
      ...
    }

    this.search = new Search(this)
    this.character = new Character(this)
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was initially looking for a solution that would make invoking this.endpoint work on its own, without the parent part, as it was behavior I had seen in other applications. I just figured out that those cases, however, were made possible with Function.prototype.bind(), which I guess won't be quite as easy to implement in my use case as I thought. I'm marking your answer as correct because it seems to be the better way to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think it is better to specify your needs for Character and Search in the constructors so it is more clear and easy to follow. So it can look like that

```
class API {
    constructor(apikey, options = {}) {
        /* some logic... */
        const context = {
            endpoint: 'https://some.site/',
            globalQueries: {
                key: apikey,
                language: options.lang || 'en',
            },
        }
        this.context = context;

        this.search = new Search(context)
        this.character = new Character(context)
    }
}

class Character {
    constructor (context) {
      this.context = context
    }

    look (name, params = {}) {
      request({
        uri: this.context.endpoint,
        qs: Object.assign(this.context.globalQueries, params),
        json: true
      })
    }
  }
```

So the context object is to be shared between parents and their children

Comment: I like the thought of accessing it the same way on both files, so that's it's not `this.context.element` in children and `this.element` in the parent! Thanks.